# Is it possible to define hook functions in template.php instead of the module?

Tags: theming, hooks, forms

Theme functions are defined in the `template.php` but is it possible to define hook functions in there? for example There is a content type called `phone-book`, its add content form ID is `phone-book-node`, I want it to redirect to my custom page when it is submitted. so I created this function in the `template.php` :

```
function MYTHEME_form_phone_book_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
$form_state['redirect'] = 'go/some/where';
}
```

but it doesn't work. I don't know if it is totally impossible to define such hook functions inside `template.php` or something is wrong with my code.

Comment: I'm pretty sure [any alter hook can go in template.php](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11874291/967168) or a custom module.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can implement *any* alter hook in a theme, as well as  `hook_theme()` and preprocess hooks.

Adding `$form_state['redirect']` won't do anything there, though. You need to do that in a submit handler:

```
function MYTHEME_form_phone_book_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#submit'][] = 'MYTHEME_phone_book_node_form_submit';
}

function MYTHEME_phone_book_node_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'go/some/where';
}
```

To ensure that your hook is running, get the Devel module installed and add `dpm('alive');` in there. Then clear the caches (to be sure) and refresh the page a couple of times. If you don't see the debug message, the hook isn't being called, and it might be named incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks. I did this but I saw no debug message. the hook is not being called

Comment: Then it's likely the function is named wrong (check the name of your content type), or you haven't cleared the caches...

Comment: Please look at this screenshot of Firebug `http://i.cubeupload.com/4wwXbs.png` every thing seems to be right but after node submission the form is redirected to the node page.

Comment: Are you trying to keep the user on the same page after submitting the form? If so, try [Add another](https://drupal.org/project/addanother)

Comment: Yes, I'm tying to keep it one same page

Comment: It works very well on adding a node but on node edit I still have the problem

Comment: another solution is to use `rule` module and add a rule/action statement.

Comment: Good point @Drupalist, that's a good solution

Comment: To be pedantic, you can also implement process hooks and theme hooks in a theme.