# what can replace hook

Tags: hooks

I am a newbie into Drupal.

what else other than module name can replace 'hook' from any hook function in Drupal? 
For ex. 
"myModule" replaces hook in hook_form_alter and defined as 'myModule_form_alter'

Comment: I updated my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are particularly looking at theme hooks following from https://www.packtpub.com/books/content/drupal-7-module-development-drupals-theme-layer can be useful.

> All preprocess functions run before all process functions template_
>   prefixed functions run frst. [module]_ prefixed functions run next.
>   [theme]_ prefixed functions run last Multi-hook functions run before
>   hook-specific functions This results in the following order of
>   execution for a particular theme hook:
>
> template_preprocess()
>
> template_preprocesss_HOOK()
>
> MODULE_preprocess()
>
> THEME_preprocess()
>
> THEME_preprocess_HOOK()
>
> template_process()
>
> template_processs_HOOK()
>
> MODULE_process()
>
> MODULE_process_HOOK()
>
> THEME_process()
>
> THEME_process_HOOK()

Answer (score 1):

Any **alter hook** and **preprocess hooks** that is defined inside a module can also be defined inside the theme as well. So if you are using *Bartik* theme you can open the *Bartik*'s template.php file and use

```
function bartik_form_alter(){}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Checking the [Is it possible to define hook functions in template.php instead of the module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/111262/is-it-possible-to-define-hook-functions-in-template-php-instead-of-the-module) can also be helpful.